# LINQ Order by question

Tags: linq, sorting

I have a linq query that returns a list of employees and a job title.
I need to sort it by job title but have the ones that do not have any employees in the output list first.

Example sorted:
- Driver          List{0}
- Attendant  List{71}
- Pilot               List{19}

The driver is first because it has nothing in the list and then it is sorted by title.

I am just curious what do you think would be my best option to accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the list" - is this a list of subordinates for each employee?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
var query = employees.OrderBy(x => x.Subordinates.Any() ? 1 : 0)
                     .ThenBy(x => x.JobTitle);
```

You could also use the fact that `false` sorts earlier than `true`:

```
var query = employees.OrderBy(x => !x.Subordinates.Any())
                     .ThenBy(x => x.JobTitle);
```

... but that's a little bit less obvious, IMO.

Comment: perfect tx, my method was little overkill before

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Jobs.OrderBy(j => j.Eployees.Count()).ThenBy(j => j.Name);
```

Comment: No, because that would put "Pilot" as second. It's not the count itself, it's just "is the count non-zero".

Comment: That's right. I only fully understood the OP's full intent after seeing your answer. At that stage it seemed silly to update mine to be the same as yours.